# PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I am getting the error message:

```
Warning: PDOStatement::execute(): SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in /var/www/calendar/insert.php on line 17
```

but I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I have an `INSERT` statement using 6 binds and I am binding 6, so where is the mismatch?

### Code

**Insert**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO bookings (forename, surname, badge, department, start, end) VALUES (:forename, :surname, :badge, :department, STR_TO_DATE(:dp1,'%Y-%m-%d'), STR_TO_DATE(:dp2,'%Y-%m-%d'))");
```

**Binds**

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $stmt->bindParam('$key', $value);
  echo "Binding $key as $value <br>";
}
```

which outputs:

```
Binding forename as John
Binding surname as Doe
Binding badge as 1 
Binding department as Days 
Binding dp1 as 2014-10-06 
Binding dp2 as 2014-10-10
```

Comment: Shouldn't `'$key'` just be `$key` ?

Answer (score 2):

Since you're using single quotes, the variables are not interpolated, you need to change them to double quotes:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
  $stmt->bindParam(":$key", $_POST[$key]); // assuming $key matches those named placeholders

}
```

Edit: A good insight regarding comments as eloquently stated @marc, you're getting the last value by just using `$value`.

Comment: Thanks. It works now without the error message but the insert is using  `2014-10-10` on all columns?

Comment: @user3973427 what do you mean? isn't it `dp1 = 2014-10-06` and `dp2 = 2014-10-10`?

Comment: bindParam essentially sets up a reference to the bound varaible. since you're binding to `$value` in a loop, you're binding to the VARIABLE $value, not the value it contains for a particular iteration - which means you'll pick up the LAST value of the loop. try binding to `$_POST[$key]` instead

Answer (score 0):

- No need for single quotes `'`
- No need for colon `:`
- use `bindValue` instead

---

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    $stmt->bindValue($key, $value);
}
```